# how i handle sql injection in this code with pdo->prefer?

Tags: php, pdo, sql-injection

in this function,and other function such as this,for update,delet and insert,how i can handle sql injection in this code with pdo->prefer?

```
function get_rows($fields = '*', $where = ' 1=1 ') {
$this->_query = "select $fields from {$this->table} where {$where}";
$stm = $this->_pdo->query($this->_query);
if(!$stm)
die(var_export($this->_pdo->errorinfo(), TRUE));
else
return $stm->fetchAll();}


function insert($fields, $data) {
    $this->_query = " insert into $this->table ($fields) VALUES ($data)";
    $this->_pdo->exec($this->_query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the API documentation of the prepared statement from [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php):

First, create a prepared statement with placeholders. Next, bind the placeholders with your variables, and call the execute method that PDO offers.

So your function could look like:

```
function insert($fields, $data) {
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$this->table ."(fields, values) VALUES (:fields, :values)");
   $stmt->bindParam(':fields', $fields);
   $stmt->bindParam(':fields', $values);
   $stmt->execute();
```

}

Please note that it depends on how exactly you provide the names and values parameter if you have to make some additional adjustments, but I expect you get the gist from the example. Use bindParam to bind the parameters in the prepared statement, and then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

`prepare()` would not help much since you decided to create your own PDO wrapper functions.

Binding columns and table is not supported in `PDO`.

At this point you are at your own risk, escaping characters, sql injection ...

It is probably understandle for tables and columns, you can use an array of hardcoded strings and then throw an error if not found:

```
if (!in_array($field, $list_of_fields)) {
    throw new MyPDOException('Field not found');
}
```

As for the value again, you have to do some work to clean them up, so you see a lot of work that you did not have to do ?

Maybe it's a simple CRUD app but what if you have to run a JOIN query? are you going to create a function for that ?

It's going to get messy, I suggest you to write the pure PDO code as you are going to end up re-writing your own library as you get limited.